# counting a distance between vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, numerical-linear-algebra

I found such an excercise and I'm thinking about mathematical explanation of it:

Suppose that we generated a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{100\times10}$ - it has $100$ rows in $\mathbb{R}^{10}$. I have to write a function which gives a gives a distnace between each pair of vectors, but without any loops and iterations, just in one line. We have the standard metric
$$d(x,y)=\Vert x-y\Vert_2^2=\sum_i|x_i-y_i|^2.$$

Is there any trick to do this from the mathematical point of view or it's rather computer's technics?

Comment: Just write the whole code in $1$ line .....pun intended 

Comment: thanks a lot :D :D

Comment: Do you need a deep mathematical interpretation(which I do not know), or something like for the pair $(i,j)$ we can use $\sqrt{((A^{\top}e_i- A^{\top}e_j)^{\top}(A^{\top}e_i-A^{\top}e_j)}$ to find the distance between vector $i$ and $j$?

Comment: I don't know exactly cause my friend told me about such problem but any formula is helpful :)

Comment: Oke, well, if it is purely about coding up a function then something of the form `norm(A(i,:)-A(j,:))` should also do the trick.

Comment: Do you have to find the distance between *all* pairs of vectors or just a specific given pair? A key identity will be $\|x-y\|^2=\langle x,x\rangle-\langle x,y\rangle-\langle y,x\rangle+\langle y,y\rangle$. All of the terms on the r.h.s. are elements of $A^TA$.

Comment: I'm not sure how should the result look like, but it would be nice to get a symmetric matrix (as a solution), where $a_{(ij)}$ is equal to distance vectors $i$ and $j$.